# Why I'm getting <prototype> object with every API call

Tags: typescript, rest, fetch-api, jsonplaceholder

I'm using [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) with Angular. I'm learning these things so my question may not be framed very well. I carefully followed the documentation and I'm getting correct output also. But there is something extra that I'm getting with every object. See,

[image]

In this example I'm fetching the record with `id: 1`. But later there will be thousands of such records and it will look very dirty. But there is no such thing mentioned in their entire documentation. How do I filter this out. My typescript code is extremely simple.

**card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchAllRecords();
  }

  fetchAllRecords() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
  }
}
```

And here I've created an [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzmmh6) also. Please correct me.

Comment: Those are the properties which all objects inherit (unless you go out of your way to make an object with a null prototype). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype  Is there some reason you don't want them?

Comment: No there's no strong reason. I was bit curious because my output is quite different from their output. I thought It may fail unit test cases later. I don't know.

Comment: Different browsers will implement console.log in different ways. You're just using a browser that gives more details about the object in its logging.

Comment: I mean, why keep unnecessary information. I don't want to harvest it.

Comment: The only own properties your object has are id, title, and userId. The rest are inherited. If you never call, for example, `toString`, then that code never needs to run. There is no memory overhead and no performance overhead.

Comment: I tried with Firefox, Chrome and Edge. Output is same everywhere. And If this isn't a big issue then I will go ahead with this. You people are expert. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your API call is working. That's all it loads are the fields of id, title and userId. That thing below is just something you can ignore. It's basically just irrelevant info to show browser properties of the object that you are already displaying above.